# Database table is not creating automatically using Maven

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven

I have been working on Maven Project, I build the project in Eclipse successfully but database table is not creating automatically, so have removed the project the completely from Eclipse and also deleted .m2 (repository) folder and created new project using

Import -> Existing Maven Project...

still the error persist...

POM.XML

```
<profile>
   <id>dev</id>
   <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
   <properties>
     <db.url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dms</db.url>
     <db.username>root</db.username>
     <db.password>admin123</db.password>
     <db.defaultAutoCommit>false</db.defaultAutoCommit>
   </properties>
</profile>
```

db.properties

```
db.password=admin123
db.username=root
db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dms
db.schema=dms
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.defaultAutoCommit=false
```

also tried...

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Error from the TOMCAT server

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dms] in context with path [/dms] threw exception [Request     processing failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session     for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open     connection] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:926)
```

User Variable Path

```
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;%M2_HOME%\bin
```

System Variable [Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW8VE.png)

stuck on this for long time, please give me a directions! Thanks

Comment: check your credentials

Comment: Thanks @atishshimpi, have checked it is all the same.

Comment: The error message states `Cannot open connection`.

Comment: Thanks @Hannes, have checked and tried again but still it gives the same error **Cannot open connection**

Comment: We need more context here. Please provide your code.

Comment: Thanks @Hannes, after removing first three lines from db.properties, 
db.schema=dms
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.defaultAutoCommit=false
now it's connecting to database and creating tables automatically. Great!

Answer (score 0):

The root error message is

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Maybe it helps to change the following line

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dms
```

to

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dms
```

Comment: Thanks @DirkNM, even after changing the line, still its not connecting, gives the same error.